# Отсутствует перевод кнопки "Propose tag info"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, описание-метки

При отсутствии описания у метки после нажатия ссылки **Подробнее...** ([к примеру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/builder/info), у метки [builder](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/builder)) попадаешь на страницу с предупреждением, внизу которой не переведённая кнопка "Propose tag info".

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там вообще два случая:

1. Если мало репы, то будет "Propose tag info".
   https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14667

   Добавил перевод.

   > Предложить описание метки
2. Если хватает репы, то "Create tag info". https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14663

   Добавил перевод.

   > Добавить описание метки

Comment: Пока без изменений. Когда обновится?

Comment: @AlexR. с новой версией движка. 1-2 дня обычно.

Comment: @AlexR. появилось.